# Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, python, selenium-webdriver

Estou com problemas em manipular popup. Ao que parece, o código do popup é gerado em tempo real, não sendo capturado pelo selenium. De fato, é possível ver o uso de jQuery, não detectei Ajax, mas bem capaz que tenha também.

> QUESTÃO: Meu objetivo é criar um crawler para pegar dados de várias
>   faturas por mês, e assim efetuar controle de gastos da empresa.

Segue código abaixo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://servicos.coelba.com.br/Pages/Default.aspx")

link = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_m_g_bf2869f9_4567_4bf8_bee4_c5c7c5b50e2e_ctl00_rptAplicacoes_ctl02_lnkAplicacao")
link.click()

contratoFieldName = "numcontacontrato" 
contratoFieldElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_name(contratoFieldName))
```

O problema ocorre nas duas ultimas linhas. Não consigo manipular o campo de formulário que aparece no popup (ou será window?) e assim inserir a matrícula.
Já usei o:

```
driver.current_window_handle 
driver.window_handles
```

este último só aponta um id. 
Já tentei os seguintes switches:

```
driver.switch_to                 
driver.switch_to_alert            
driver.switch_to_frame
driver.switch_to_active_element  
driver.switch_to_default_content  
driver.switch_to_window
```

Answer (score 2):

Esse popup não é um popup de verdade. Na verdade é só uma div com `position: absolute`. É um pouco complicado acessar aquele input porque ele está dentro de um iframe.

O melhor a fazer nesse caso é carregar diretamente a página do iframe:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://autoatendimento.coelba.com.br/NDP_DCSRUCES_D~home~neologw~sap.com/login.jsp?canal=hotsite&dest=26')

matricula = '0123456'
driver.find_element_by_name('numcontacontrato').send_keys(matricula)
```

Até dá pra acessar o iframe com o método `driver.switch_to.frame()`, mas estaríamos perdendo tempo carregando o frame pai, sendo que não queremos nada com ele.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que era isso que deseja fazer, mas se não for testar o link, siga a abordagem do rodorgas.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://servicos.coelba.com.br/Pages/Default.aspx")

link = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_m_g_bf2869f9_4567_4bf8_bee4_c5c7c5b50e2e_ctl00_rptAplicacoes_ctl00_lnkAplicacao")
link.click()

sleep(20) # Aqui você tem que mapear o load e esperar ele desaparecer, da pra fazer dinamicamente.

# Frame Pai
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
# Frame Filho
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
contratoFieldElement = driver.find_element_by_id("txtContractAccount")
contratoFieldElement.send_keys('1234567')

contratoFieldElement = driver.find_element_by_id("txtContractAccount")
contrato_digitado = contratoFieldElement.get_attribute('value')

print(contrato_digitado)
```